# Hosting requirements for publishing an addin to appstore

Tags: hosting, office-js, add-in, word-addins

In order to publish an addin to appstore, do we need to host the manifest (XML) + webpage (HTML, JS) for the addin?

The documentation implies that we should host the manifest on sharepoint and the webpage for the addin on our own servers for both  the approval process, but also for end users to download and use the word addin.

The alternative is that we deliver these elements to MS and they host *they* host the addin on their servers.

Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You must host your own add-in and associated resources. Microsoft will not host your webpage on your behalf.

You should submit the manifest to Microsoft for validation via the SellerDashboard (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/upload-package))